# only show/draw the segments of curve within a given region

Tags: plotting

I'd like to show/draw only those curves within the circular region (highlighted in red), which corresponds to

> a = 0 Degree, i.e., x^2+y^2<=1,

together with the red circle.

[image]

```
range1 = 80 Degree; incr = 10 Degree; range2 = 1.5;
longitude = Table[(x - Tan[a])^2 + 
 y^2 == (1/Cos[a])^2, {a, -range1, range1, incr}];

lattitude = Table[x^2 + (y - 1/(
    If[a > 0 Degree, 
      1, -1] Cos[a]))^2 == (Tan[a])^2, {a, -range1, range1, incr}];

tab = Flatten[{longitude, lattitude, x == 0, y == 0}];

ContourPlot[tab, {x, -range2, range2}, {y, -range2, range2}, ContourStyle -> Black]
```

I've tried

```
longitude = Table[Boole[x^2+y^2<=1]*((x - Tan[a])^2 + 
 y^2 == (1/Cos[a])^2), {a, -range1, range1, incr}];
```

But it doesn't work as I thought (the evaluation is very slow).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is accomplished with `RegionFunction`:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[tab], {x, -range2, range2}, {y, -range2, range2},
 ContourStyle -> Black,
 RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2}] < 1 &)
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know this option before.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to C. E.'s answer is to use the ability of `ContourPlot[]` to plot over a region, as in the following:

```
With[{range1 = 80 °, incr = 10 °},
     longitude = Table[(x - Tan[a])^2 + y^2 == Sec[a]^2,
                       {a, -range1, range1, incr}];
     latitude = Table[x^2 + (y - 1/((1 - 2 UnitStep[-a]) Cos[a]))^2 == Tan[a]^2,
                      {a, -range1, range1, incr}];
     ContourPlot[Flatten[{longitude, latitude, x == 0, y == 0}] // Evaluate,
                 {x, y} ∈ Disk[], ContourStyle -> Black]]
```